# Does WebSocket's ClientEndpoint receive data in the same order it was sent by the ServerEndpoint?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, java-websocket

I'm using `RemoteEndpoint.Async`'s `sendText()` method in a loop to send some data to the `ClientEndPoint`. As the data is sent asynchronously from the `ServerEndpoint`, will it be received by the `ClientEndpoint` in the same order as it was sent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessary. There are always channel threads transmitting data to the clients on websocket on a single connection. Data can come in any order.Although attempt to deliver the data will be ASAP but race conditions may occurr.